# Do wound penalties apply to soak as well?

Tags: combat, ars-magica-5

Running a brief combat and it occurred to us that an opponent had a soak that would only ever allow light wounds to be accrued.  Consulting the combat rules in Ars Magica p. 178, we concluded that it should.  So we ran with that.

Was ruling to apply wound penalties to the soak of combatants correct?

Comment: @vicky_molokh-unsilenceMonica what are the derivative systems of Ars Magica?

Comment: In the narrower sense, Mage the Ascension and Awakening, but AFAIK Ars Magica had some influence on the development of other Storyteller and Storytelling games.

Comment: @vicky_molokh-unsilenceMonica Thanks.  I didn't know that connection, but was able to find some more interesting history about it [here](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Ars_Magica).  It appears that the 4th and 5th editions of Ars Magica are well after what Mage the Ascension was based on.  Might be worth a gaming history question to ellucidate how much of the combat mechanic was preserved between 3rd and 5th edition of Ars Magica.

Comment: Regarding the hypothetical gaming history question, it used to be joked in Ars Magica discussion groups that Ars has a tradition of completely rewriting the combat system for each edition.  (I believe that tradition continued all the way through to ArM5, but it's been several years since I last played it, so I'm not 100% certain.)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is unclear. Page 172 of the Ars Magica 5 core says Soak is not affected by Wound Penalties:

> note that Polandrus’ Wound Penalty does not apply to Soak because Soak is not rolled

However, page 178 states:

> The character suffers a penalty to all actions (rolls and **totals**) equal to the sum of all penalties due to his wounds

which implies that Soak Totals should be affected by Wound Penalties.

For balance, I would suggest taking the former, as Wound Penalties already apply to Defence Totals, and damage is based on the difference between the Attack Total and Defence Total. If you include Wound Penalties on soak, that means wounded characters are effectively doubly penalized.

Comment: RPG book hermeneutic commonly follow the principle that the specific overrides the general, which makes the non-applicability of wound penalties to soak an *exception* that *overrides* the general rule.

Comment: Further supporting the "no penalty" conclusion, I note that the text "rolls and totals" is being used to clarify "all actions", and Soak is not an action.